# How do I handle this

Tags: android, flutter, dart, oop, mobile

[Error on my flutter code regarding a dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8UPa.png)
Exception has occurred.
_CastError (type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'String?' in type cast)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to cast list to a string thats why you get `_CastError`, when you use "[]" in dart, you actually declare a list, so either you need to change type `String? selectedPlan` to `List<String>? selectedPlan` or just remove the brackets like `String? selectedPlan = 'FIXED DEPOSIT SAVINGS';`

And please share code as code next time :)